# Proof of the following norm inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $x,y ∈ \mathbb{R}^n$ be vectors, let $A ∈ \mathbb{R}^{n×n}$ be a regular matrix. We denote $\lambda_{min}$ as the smallest eigenvalue of matrix $A^TA$ and $\lambda_{max}$ as the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$. Then $
\frac{\| Ay\|^2}{\| Ax\|^2}≤\frac{\lambda_{max}}{\lambda_{min}}\frac{\| y\|^2}{\| x\|^2}$.

I have a problem with this proof since I can't seem to be able to connect eigenvalues of $A^TA$ with norms. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***warnning***: this is a complete solution to the posted problem.
The hints are already provided in others' answer.
I write this for people who failed to prove the inequality after seeing the hints.

---

$\forall x\in \mathbb R^n\ \langle Ax,Ax \rangle = x^T(A^TA)x$ where $B=A^T A$ is a symmetric one.
According to the `real spectral theorem`, we can orthogonally diagonalize $B=A^TA$.
Let's say that there is a orthogonal matrix $P$ which satisfies $P^T(A^TA)P=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\dots \lambda_n)$, where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues(counted with multiplicity) in non-decending order($\lambda_i\geq \lambda_{i+1}$).

Then we can make an varible change $x=Py\quad y=P^{-1}x=P^Tx$ (recall that orthogonal matrices are invertible so this is a one-to-one and onto mapping). Therefore
$$\begin{aligned}
\langle Ax,Ax\rangle&=(Py)^T(A^TA)(Py)=y^T\left(P^T(A^TA)P\right)y=y^T\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_i)y
\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
{y_1}^T\\
{y_2}^T\\
\vdots\\
{y_n}^T
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1\\
&\lambda_2\\
&&\ddots\\
&&&\lambda_n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
{y_1}
&{y_2}
&\dots
&{y_n}
\end{bmatrix}
=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i y_i^2\\
\\
&\lambda_1\sum y_i^2=\lambda_1||y||^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i y_i^2\leq \lambda_n\sum y_i^2=\lambda_n ||y||^2\\
&\text{orthogonal matrices preserve norm so }||x||=||Px||=||y||\text{ thus}\\
&\lambda_n||y||^2=\lambda_n||x||^2\leq ||Ax||^2=\langle Ax,Ax\rangle\leq \lambda_1||y||^2=\lambda_1 ||x||^2\\
\implies &\lambda_1||x||\geq ||Ax||^2\geq \lambda_n ||x||
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Back to the original problem. We have $||Ax||\in \left[\ \lambda_n ||x||,\lambda_1 ||x||\ \right]$ and $||Ay||\in \left[\ \lambda_n ||y||,\lambda_1 ||y||\ \right]$.

$$
\frac{||Ax||^2}{||Ay||^2}\leq \frac{\lambda_1 ||x||^2}{||Ay||}\leq \frac{\lambda_1 ||x||^2}{\lambda_n ||y||^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints: $\left\lVert Ax\right\rVert^2=x^{T}A^{T}Ax$ and $A^TA$ is symmetric, hence orthogonally diagonalizable.

Comment: Thank you! This means that $\frac{\| Ay\|^2}{\| Ax\|^2}=\frac{y^{T}A^{T}Ay}{x^{T}A^{T}Ax}$. I wrote vectors as $x=\sum_{i=1}^nc_{i}u_{i}$ where $c_{1},...,c_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u_{1},...,u_{n}$ are eigenvectors of $A^TA$. Then $A^{T}A\sum_{i=1}^nc_{i}u_{i} = \sum_{i=1}^nc_{i}A^{T}Au_{i} = \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_{i}c_{i}u_{i}$. When I applied this to the inequality I get $\frac{y^{t}\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_{i}d_{i}u_{i}}{x^{t}\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_{i}c_{i}u_{i}}\leq\frac{\lambda_{max}}{\lambda_{min}}\frac{y^{t}\sum_{i=1}^nd_{i}u_{i}}{x^{t}\sum_{i=1}^nc_{i}u_{i}}$. I believe at this part its proven.

Answer (score 0):

Using the hint provided by leoli1, you can prove the following result:
\begin{equation}
\left\lVert Ax\right\rVert \leq \lambda_{max}\left\lVert x\right\rVert
\end{equation}
You can try setting the coordonates of x$\in \mathbb{R}^n$ in an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $A^TA$ and see what happends when computing $x^TA^TAx$.

The same idea apply for the inequality with $\lambda_{min}$.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I think it helped me with constructing the proof I wrote as a response to the comment by leoli1.